# ASP.NET MVC MOQ - Modifed public ActionResult LogOn to include Session Object - Unit Test Failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm pretty new to Unit Testing and MOQ etc. I've modified public ActionResult `LogOn(LogOnModel model)` Action to inlclude `Session["UserFullName"]` for logging purpose.

Unfortunately, the Unit Test is failing with Object Reference not set for `Session["UserFullName"]`.

Could anyone please tell me how to resolive this issue using MOQ by modifying `GetAccountController()` method on unit test?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpSessionStateBase is made available through the HttpContextBase.  You can set the HttpContextBase via the ControllerContext.  This is how I do it using RhinoMocks.

```
 var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
 var session = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpSessionStateBase>();

 httpContext.Expect( c => c.Session ).Return( session ).Repeat.AtLeastOnce();
 session.Expect( s => s["UserFullName"] ).Return( "John Q. User" );

 var controller = GetAccountController();
 controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext( httpContext, new RouteData(), controller );

 ...
```